# map don't read every record of a sorted Dataframe with the right order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

hello Stack community I am new in Scala and Spark coding and I trying to map each record of a sorted data-frame and the map instead of take one by one the row it read them random  or 3 together.The data-frame is sorted and stored in variable data which contains

```
|0.04|0.03|
| 0.1|0.02|
|0.07|0.06|
|0.02|0.12| 
|0.05|0.09|
|0.01|0.15|
|0.16|0.01| 
|0.05|0.14|
|0.14|0.05|
|0.09|0.13|
|0.13| 0.1|


 val d = data.rdd.map(x=> {println(x)})
    println(d.count())
```

i expect this output:

```
[0.04,0.03]
[ 0.1,0.02]
[0.07,0.06]
[0.02,0.12] 
[0.05,0.09]
[0.01,0.15]
[0.16,0.01] 
[0.05,0.14]
[0.14,0.05]
[0.09,0.13]
[0.13, 0.1]
```

but i have this:

```
[0.07,0.06]
[0.05,0.09]
[0.02,0.12]
[0.04,0.03]
[0.1,0.02]
[0.01,0.15]
[0.09,0.13]
[0.16,0.01]
[0.13,0.1]
[0.05,0.14]
[0.14,0.05]
```

Comment: spark is distributed, it will only print in order if you have 1 single partition

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In Spark your data is likely be distributed across different partitions. Thus you cannot guarantee the order of `println` statements.

You can check which row belongs to which partition like;

```scala
data.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, part) => { 
   part.map(row => (index,row))
}).foreach(d => println(d))
```

Or you can use `.coalesce(1)` function to reduce the partition count to 1. This will create a new dataset with 1 partition.

Comment: Thanks for your help